# Internet connection problem - Aspire-V5-591G

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, acer

I recently bought an Aspire-V5-591G. I installed ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10. I was not experiencing any problem with my internet connection on windows.

On ubuntu I have never managed to connect by ethernet or wifi, except from my phone's wifi hotspot. Somehow I could connect to that.

I tried many solutions, but I ended up blocking the hotspot wifi as well.

Can someone guide me in order to solve the problem?

This is what I have already tried:

1) [Link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707746/qualcom-atheros-wirelless-adapter-not-recognized-in-my-acer-v-nitro-laptop/707805#707805) then [Link 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726271/wifi-ol-lenovo-ideapad-300-15isk-atheros-qca9377/726324#726324)

2) [Link 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763080/no-wifi-in-qualcom-atheros-ubuntu-16-04-acer-aspire-e-15)

After updating my ubuntu version, I established an ethernet connection. I can connect to the internet. Yet the wifi connection doesn't work again.

> **output**: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`
>
> 07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac      >Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
>     Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network >Adapter [11ad:0807]
>     Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
>     Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
>
> 08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. >RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev >15)
>
> **output** `iwconfig`:
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> enp8s0    no wireless extensions.
>
> wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any
>            Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off
>            Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>            Power Management:on

```
    rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Please *please* ***please*** do not post pictures of text! Just copy/paste the text if possible into your answer. It makes everyone's life infinitely easier. (case in point, output of Pilot6's command)

Comment: OK. Then post the output of `rfkill list`. Please use the `{}` button for formatting.

Comment: I executed the command rfkill list while i was connected to the ethernet..If you want me to go offline first,then execute, tell me..

Answer (score 0):

Well, my only suggestion is to start over from scratch.

At the top of the screen you will either see two arrow pointing in different directions, or an icon that looks like a pie slice. Right click on that to expose the menu.

At the bottom of the menu click on **'Edit Connections'**. You should get a dialog box right in the middle that lists all connections. Click on each one individually and then click on **'Delete'**.

Once all the connections have been deleted, in the same dialog box click on **'Add'**. You will presented with another dialog box that has a line item 'Ethernet'. Click on **'Create'**.

You will then be presented with another dialog box with multiple tabs. Click on the tab that says **IPv4 Settings**. It will then display a dialog that should say 'Automatic DHCP'. If it does not then use the drop down to set it and then click on **'Save'**.

Reboot the OS and see if you have connectivity.

This is my only suggestion since I am not that familiar with networks. If you have a weird network card then a driver might be the problem, but other than that I have no suggestions.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot. This will blacklist the `acer_wmi` module that is blocking your Wi-Fi.

Comment: It did not work. :S

Comment: I fixed a typo in the command. Try again.